# How do you pipe the visualizer output of drake to a port using MeshCat with pydake?

Tags: drake

How do you setup MeshCat on an exposed port as an online interface to interact my drake program? Looking for a short example in pydrake. Presently attempting on Ubuntu 18.04 with pydrake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/165da3960ce2aede5558b27a6102d66bafa70b03/manipulation/util/geometry_inspector.py#L169

The header of that file also has some useful instructions.